# Parsing XML in IE with jQuery

Tags: jquery, xml, internet-explorer, cross-browser

I am having some trouble parsing xml with jQuery. I have a fragment of xml text and I would like to extract a certain node's value. But this isn't working in IE. It works fine in Chrome.

```
$(function () {
    var xmlText = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?><dog_info><keyspec><keycaps><aes /><v-clock /></keycaps><dog>';
    xmlText += '<dogid>566578105</dogid><memoryinfo><access>read/write</access>';
    xmlText += '<fileid>65524</fileid><size>128</size></memoryinfo></dog></keyspec></dog_info>';
    alert($(xmlText).find("dogid").text()); //this do not work in ie
})
```

Comment: IE (older versions anyway) tends to not be a fan of arbitrarily named elements not defined in the HTML spec, so you can't reliably use HTML parsing on plain-old xml  elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem could be the use of html parsing for xml content, so try to use [$.parseXML()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsexml/)

```
$(function () {
    var xmlText = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?><dog_info><keyspec><keycaps><aes /><v-clock /></keycaps><dog>';
    xmlText += '<dogid>566578105</dogid><memoryinfo><access>read/write</access>';
    xmlText += '<fileid>65524</fileid><size>128</size></memoryinfo></dog></keyspec></dog_info>';

    var doc = $.parseXML(xmlText);
    var $xml = $(doc);

    alert($xml.find("dogid").text()); //this do not work in ie
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this?

```
 <script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(function(){
        var xmlText= '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?><dog_info><keyspec><keycaps><aes /><v-clock /></keycaps><dog>';
        xmlText += '<dogid>566578105</dogid><memoryinfo><access>read/write</access>';
        xmlText += '<fileid>65524</fileid><size>128</size></memoryinfo></dog></keyspec></dog_info>';
        var xmlDoc = $.parseXML(xmlText); // convert string to xml document first
        alert($(xmlDoc).find("dogid").text());//this do not work in ie
    })
</script>
```